# How to extract tables vertically in R

Tags: r, tabulizer

The below code extracts tables from pdf and puts in into CSV horizontally, 
can someone help me how to extract each page's tables vertically in to csv?

```
library(tabulizer)
pdf_file <- "new.pdf"

result<- extract_tables(pdf_file, pages =c(89,90,91), output = "data.frame")
write.csv(result,'result.csv')
```

Comment: Please help me on the above code

Comment: try write.csv(t(result),'result.csv')